# Why does form always return invalid?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I prepopulated my edit form inputs based on API response

[image]

When I clicked on Continue, validate() will trigger.

```
validate() {
    this.$refs.form.validate()
    console.log('this.$refs.form.validate() == ', this.$refs.form.validate())
```

I have no idea why it kept returning **false**

As you can see, Name, Description, Timezone, Start Date, Start Time, End Date, End Time all are there provided. The form should be valid.

**Codes**

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid class="my-1">
        <Navbar />
        <Breadcrumbs />
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
                <v-card elevation="2">
                    <PanelHeader type="update" icon="campaign" title="Campaigns" />

                    <v-stepper v-model="e1" justify="center" elevation="0">
                        <v-stepper-header>
                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1"> Campaign </v-stepper-step>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 2" step="2"> Setup </v-stepper-step>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <v-stepper-step step="3"> Finish </v-stepper-step>
                        </v-stepper-header>

                        <v-stepper-items>
                            <v-stepper-content step="1">
                                <v-card class="mb-12" elevation="0">
                                    <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation v-model="valid" id="form">
                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-card-text class="font-weight-bold">
                                                Campaigns
                                                <v-tooltip right>
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                                            <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">info</v-icon>
                                                        </v-btn>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <span>Select marketing campaign type for Print Materials or Product Tags. Provide a name to identify the marketing campaign.</span>
                                                </v-tooltip>
                                            </v-card-text>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                <v-select disabled dense outlined :items="types" label="Type" v-model="form.values.type" :rules="form.rules.type"></v-select>
                                            </v-col>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.name" :rules="form.rules.name" label="Name" required></v-text-field>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>
                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                <v-textarea dense rows="1" outlined v-model="form.values.description" label="Description" required></v-textarea>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-card-text class="font-weight-bold"
                                                >Schedule :

                                                <v-tooltip right>
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                                            <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">info</v-icon>
                                                        </v-btn>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <span>Set the time zone, start and end date for this campaign to be active.</span>
                                                </v-tooltip>
                                            </v-card-text>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                <v-select dense outlined :items="timezones" v-model="form.values.timezone" :rules="form.rules.timezone" label="Timezone" append-icon="lock_clock"></v-select>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu v-model="form.values.startDateMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.startDate" :rules="form.rules.startDate" label="Start Date" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-date-picker v-model="form.values.startDate"></v-date-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu ref="menu" v-model="startTimeMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" :return-value.sync="form.values.startTime" transition="scale-transition" offset-y max-width="290px" min-width="290px">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense v-model="form.values.startTime" label="Start Time" append-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" outlined></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-time-picker v-if="startTimeMenu" v-model="form.values.startTime" full-width @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(form.values.startTime)"></v-time-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu v-model="endDateMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.endDate" :rules="form.rules.endDate" :min="form.values.startDate" label="End Date" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-date-picker v-model="form.values.endDate"></v-date-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu ref="menu" v-model="endTimeMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" :return-value.sync="form.values.endTime" transition="scale-transition" offset-y max-width="290px" min-width="290px">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense v-model="form.values.endTime" label="End Time" append-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" outlined></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-time-picker v-if="endTimeMenu" v-model="form.values.endTime" :min="form.values.startTime" full-width @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(form.values.endTime)"></v-time-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>
                                    </v-form>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn color="primary" @click="validate()" :disabled="!valid"> Continue </v-btn>
                                <router-link :to="`/${segment1}`">
                                    <v-btn text> Cancel </v-btn>
                                </router-link>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="3"> </v-stepper-content>
                        </v-stepper-items>
                    </v-stepper>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '../../../components/Navbar'
import Breadcrumbs from '../../../components/Breadcrumbs'
import PanelHeader from '../../../components/PanelHeader'
import axios from 'axios'
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

export default {
    components: {
        Navbar,
        Breadcrumbs,
        PanelHeader
    },
    beforeMount() {},
    computed: {
        segment1: function () {
            const firstSegment = new URL(window.location.href).pathname.split('/')[1]
            return `${firstSegment}`
        },
        timeZone: function () {
            console.log('timeZone')
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.getCampaign()
    },
    data() {
        return {
            campaign: {},
            form: {
                errors: {},
                values: {
                    name: '',
                    type: '',
                    description: '',
                    timezone: '',
                    startDate: '',
                    endDate: '',
                    startTime: moment().format('HH:mm'),
                    endTime: '24:00',
                    urlType: 'Single',
                    url: 'https://',
                    attribute: '',
                    operator: '',
                    value: ''
                },
                rules: {
                    type: [(v) => !!v || 'Type is required'],
                    name: [(v) => !!v || 'Name is required'],
                    startDate: [(v) => !!v || 'Start Date is required'],
                    endDate: [(v) => !!v || 'End Date is required'],
                    timezone: [(v) => !!v || 'Timezone is required'],
                    startTime: [(v) => !!v || 'Start Time is required'],
                    endTime: [(v) => !!v || 'End Time is required'],
                    urlType: [(v) => !!v || 'URL Type is required'],
                    url: [(v) => !!v || 'URL is required'],
                    attribute: [(v) => !!v || 'Attribute is required'],
                    operator: [(v) => !!v || 'Operator is required'],
                    value: [(v) => !!v || 'Value is required']
                }
            },
            e1: 1,
            valid: false,
            valid2: false,
            types: ['Product', 'Marketing'],
            operator: [],
            operators: ['=', '!=', 'in', 'not in'],
            value: [],
            values: ['Italy', 'Finland', 'Norway'],
            timezones: moment.tz.names(),
            startDateMenu: false,
            endDateMenu: false,
            startTimeMenu: false,
            endTimeMenu: false,
            urlTypes: ['Single', 'Multiple'],
            attributes: []
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'form.values.attribute'() {
            this.operator = null
            axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            let data = {
                $root: 'vc_operator',
                op: 'read',
                brand: 'COLM',
                selection: {
                    filters: [`id:${this.form.values.attribute}`]
                },
                _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
            }
            axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, data).then((response) => {
                this.operators = response.data.operators
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getAllData(id) {
            let myForm = document.getElementById(id)
            console.log(
                Array.from(myForm.elements).map((e) => {
                    return e.value
                })
            )
        },
        getCampaign() {
            let filters = 'id:' + this.$route.params.id
            let body = {
                $root: 'vc_campaign',
                op: 'read',
                brand: 'COLM',
                selection: {
                    filters: [filters]
                },
                _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
            }

            axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'applcation/json'
            axios
                .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, body)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.data.status == 0) {
                        this.campaign = response.data.campaigns[0]
                        this.form.values.name = this.campaign.name
                        this.form.values.description = this.campaign.description
                        this.form.values.timezone = this.campaign.time_zone

                        // console.log(this.campaign.start_date.split('T')[0])

                        // this.form.values.startDate = this.campaign.start_date.split("T");

                        this.form.values.startDate = this.campaign.start_date.split('T')[0]
                        this.form.values.endDate = this.campaign.end_date.split('T')[0]

                        this.form.values.startTime = this.campaign.start_date.split('T')[1]
                        this.form.values.endTime = this.campaign.end_date.split('T')[1]
                    } else {
                        alert(response.data.statustext)
                        reject(response.data.statustext)
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Something went wrong: ', err)
                })
        },
        validate() {
            this.$refs.form.validate()
            console.log('this.$refs.form.validate() == ', this.$refs.form.validate())

            if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
                if (this.campaign.type_id == 2) {
                    let attributes = {
                        $root: 'vc_rule_attribute',
                        op: 'read',
                        brand: 'COLM',
                        _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
                    }

                    axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'applcation/json'
                    axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, attributes).then((response) => {
                        this.attributes = response.data.rule_attributes
                    })
                }

                let data = {
                    name: this.form.values.name,
                    description: this.form.values.description,
                    start_date: this.startDateAndStartTime,
                    end_date: this.endDateAndEndTime,
                    time_zone: this.form.values.timezone,
                    priority: '100',
                    status_id: 1,
                    type_id: 1
                }

                console.log('data', data)

                let body = {
                    $root: 'vc_campaign',
                    op: 'update',
                    brand: 'COLM',
                    campaigns: [data],
                    _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
                }

                axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
                axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, body).then((response) => {
                    // console.log(response.data.campaigns[0])
                    this.tmpCampaign = response.data.campaigns[0]

                    // console.info('here2', this.tmpCampaign)

                    let data = {
                        quantity: 1,
                        campaign_id: this.tmpCampaign.id,
                        name: this.form.values.name,
                        url: this.form.values.url
                    }

                    console.info('data =', data)

                    let body = {
                        $root: 'vc_standalone',
                        op: 'update',
                        brand: 'COLM',
                        label_headers: [data],
                        _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
                    }

                    axios
                        .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, body)
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log(response.data.label_headers[0])
                            this.labelHeader = response.data.label_headers[0]

                            if (this.labelHeader.quantity == 1) {
                                //get-serial
                                let body = {
                                    $root: 'get-serial',
                                    _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session'),
                                    eid: 'COLM',
                                    mdid: this.labelHeader.id,
                                    symbology: 'QR',
                                    version: '2Q',
                                    encode: 'ascii',
                                    format: 'PNG',
                                    scale: 15.0,
                                    bg: 'FFFFFFFF',
                                    fg: '000000FF'
                                }

                                axios
                                    .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, body, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                                    .then((response) => {
                                        console.log('get-serial', response.data)
                                        const base64 = btoa(new Uint8Array(response.data).reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''))
                                        this.qrCode = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + base64
                                    })
                                    .catch((err) => {
                                        console.log('Something went wrong: ', err)
                                    })
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log('Something went wrong: ', err)
                        })

                    this.e1 = 2

                    // console.info('here', this.tmpCampaign)
                })
            } else {
                console.error('error:', this.form.values)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

**How can I debug this further ?**

Comment: Please may you remove all the unnecessary code?

Comment: I removed some codes. Left codes might be needed for helpers.

Comment: There's still soooo much code to go through.

Comment: You have rule  `type: [(v) => !!v || 'Type is required'],` just fill `v-select` type or remove rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Screenshot page, the type is not set. but the rules said type is required. Even if it's disabled it still need to fulfill the rules you set

Comment: That's it. I was fooled by that.